# Problems with encoding, UTF8

Tags: xml, xhtml, xslt-1.0

It is impossible to represent double tilde, i.e. U+0360;

I have a huge .xml file with text written in UTF8. The text has a lot of double tildes inside. The double tilde in UTF8 chart is represented by ◌͠◌. Within the Oxygen, everything is working fine and I can see characters with double tilde, there is used DejaVu Sans. The problem starts with transformation scenario. I declared the encoding of output as UTF-8, the .xml file is itself in UTF-8,

but in spite of that the transformation scenarios return the text in the following way ⴉ͠x - i.e. the first letter is displaced by block. 
I tried different options of representing double tilde in the text, i.e. I tried to replace it with ͠ (`&#x0360;`) or Ũ (`&#0360;`) in .xml, but the result was the same, i.e. block ⴉ͠x.

Declaration of unicode in .xml file:

```
---
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
---
```

Declaration of unicode in .xsl file:

```
---
<xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8"/>
---
```

The expected result is letter + tilde + letter.

The xslt file starts with the following:

```
It starts with the following:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"                  
xmlns:a="http://relaxng.org/ns/compatibility/annotations/1.0"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:teidocx="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/teidocx/1.0"
xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
xmlns:rng="http://relaxng.org/ns/structure/1.0"
xmlns:tei="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0"
xmlns:teix="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/Examples"
xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:m="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
exclude-result-prefixes="#all" version="2.0">
<xsl:import href="../common/common.xsl"/>
<xsl:import href="../common/verbatim.xsl"/>
<xsl:import href="html_param.xsl"/>
```

Comment: First step in diagnosing this is to examine the binary stream output by the XSLT processor and see exactly what octets it contains. Then you know whether your problem is XSLT outputting the wrong octets, or the rendering software (a browser? Oxygen?) displaying them incorrectly.

Comment: Also, check the way you are invoking the XSLT transformation to make sure it's actually XSLT that's doing the serialization. For example if your XSLT output is to a DOM and the DOM is then serialized independently of the XSLT, then the encoding becomes a DOM responsibility.

Comment: I tried differently, initially I tried my own xslt file, but then I gave up with that and indicated directly TEI P5 XHTML (XML with XSLT) from Oxygen, but the result was the same, block tilde letter. Is this scenario written in a way to provide output to a DOM?
Browser is Chrome, software is Oxygen.

Comment: Solving encoding problems often involves a very precise understanding of your processing chain, with careful examination of the binary format of the files between every two stages in the chain. You need to give us that information.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As I understand this transformation scenario is standardised within Oxygen (I inserted the initial lines of this xslt to the message above). But, unfortunately, I don't know where to see the wrong octets(((